# Descargar Archivos .php con codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, archivo, descarga

Intento descargar archivos `.php` desde mi aplicación echa en `codeigniter`, al descargar cualquier tipo de `archivo` con diferente extensión todo funciona correctamente pero al intentar descargar un archivo con extensión `.php` al descargarlo dentro del archivo me agrega el texto `No Access Allow` quiero creer que es seguridad de `codeigniter`, mi pregunta es ¿Abra una forma de burlar esta seguridad y se descargue el archivo y contenido tal cual?

//descargar Archivo 
con este codigo descargo cualquier tipo de archivos pero los .php me marca el mensaje que mencione:

```
<a href="http://localhost/Proyec/Pruebas/archivo.php" download="archivo.php"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-1x" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #f44336;"></i><span style="color: black; font-size:1.2em;"> archivo.php</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes solucionar permitiendo `CORS` dentro del constructor de tu `Controller` con:

```
public function __construct()
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Y para descargar el archivo basta con que lo pongas de esta manera:

```
<a href="http://localhost/Proyec/Pruebas/archivo.php" download>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-1x" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #f44336;"></i> 
      <span style="color: black; font-size:1.2em;"> archivo.php</span>
</a>
```